# Rainbow colours to every row in the ssrs report in the same order upto last row

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssrs-2012

How to give Rainbow colours to every  7 rows in the ssrs report in the same order upto last row ?

How to write that expression?
Can anyone help me out.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily using `CHOOSE`.

```
=choose((ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 7)+1 , "LIGHTBLUE","Yellow", "SILVER","Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange")
```

First we get the `ROWNUMBER` do a `MOD 7` (divide it by 7 and find the remainder) . This will give us a number from 0 to 6 so then we add one to this result as `CHOOSE` is 1 based, then simply supply a list of colours as the choice list.

Comment: Thanks, Alan.  This code is absolutely correct.  If you literally want the rainbow (roygbiv), it would be this: `=choose((ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 7) + 1 , "Violet", "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Indigo")` Color order is adjusted to make red first

Comment: Thank you so much alan schofield... Worked perfectly